# VPN used while updating files to VPS via FTP (WinSCP) - what IP is logged?

Tags: vpn, ftp

When I went out for holiday I was working on my websites on local WI-Fi, I was connected all the time with Surfshark VPN.

I’m sure that my location is secured but what about the situation where I uploaded something via FTP? Do logs show my real IP then or the VPN's?

Comment: The depends on how the VPN was configured and how to engaged the FTP connection.

Comment: What about logs?

Comment: "What about logs?" -- what do you mean? What logs? Who's logs?